# Access page secured by htaccess in chromium directly (angularjs error appears)

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, raspbian, chromium

I experienced an strange error in `angularjs` when I use `.htaccess` (`AuthType Basic`) within `chromium`.

If I access the page 'in an normal way' the user and password promt get shown from the browser. If I enter them `angularjs` (and the rest of the page) **is working** perfectly fine!

But when I access the page with embedded credentials, e.g. like this: `http://user:password@domain.com/directory` I get the following warnung:

> [Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

which due to its 'just' a warning, it should not cause the issue.
But along this the following error gets shown as well (which stops the page from working):

```
 angular.js:14700 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=myController
    at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:10973
    at da (angular.js:10050)
    at q (angular.js:9820)
    at f (angular.js:9174)
    at f (angular.js:9177)
    at angular.js:9039
    at angular.js:1954
    at m.$eval (angular.js:18423)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18523)
```

any clue why this error gets show, or better, how to avoid this error? Using non-embedded credentials the error is **not** appearing and the exact same code is working perfectly fine.

When I use e.g. chrome both approaches are working great as well. The issue just appears using the combination of chromium and embedded credentials.

PS: my chromium is running on raspbian in case this matter.

Comment: This warning should appear in recent Chrome and Chromium versions. If you don't see it in Chrome, consider upgrading it or install recent portable Chromium. Since the question doesn't contain enough debugging information, you're the only person who can check what's wrong. I guess this won't be easy on Raspbian. So network tab in desktop Chrome/Chromium should reveal all details that can explain the error.

Comment: @estus thx for the hint with the network tab. Actually the JS files linked with an relativ path get bocked. They need to have have the absolut path in order to get loaded ... strange but an workaround :)